# Wrong output out of UDF in Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I want to add a new column called academics_category, which contains the values academic degree and no academic degree.
I created a udf function who checks if a bildungsstand (education) matches to a academic degree or not.

**The problem is, that every value in the output is no academic degree.**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def academics_category(academics):
  if academics == "Bachelors":
    return "academic degree"
  elif academics == "Masters":
    return "academic degree"
  else:
    return "no academic degree"
  
academics_udf = udf(academics_category,StringType())
dfAdult = dfAdult.withColumn('academics_category',academics_udf(dfAdult['bildungsstand']))


bildung = dfAdult.groupBy('bildungsstand','bildungslevel').count().sort('bildungslevel').show(20)

+-------------+-------------+-----+
|bildungsstand|bildungslevel|count|
+-------------+-------------+-----+
|    Preschool|          1.0|   51|
|      1st-4th|          2.0|  168|
|      5th-6th|          3.0|  333|
|      7th-8th|          4.0|  646|
|          9th|          5.0|  514|
|         10th|          6.0|  933|
|         11th|          7.0| 1175|
|         12th|          8.0|  433|
|      HS-grad|          9.0|10501|
| Some-college|         10.0| 7291|
|    Assoc-voc|         11.0| 1382|
|   Assoc-acdm|         12.0| 1067|
|    Bachelors|         13.0| 5355|
|      Masters|         14.0| 1723|
|  Prof-school|         15.0|  576|
|    Doctorate|         16.0|  413|
+-------------+-------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my case. The root Dataset had spaces in the string values. I replaced the spaces with the trim function and the creation of a new DataFrame.

```
dfAdult = dfAdult.withColumn("bildungsstand_trim",trim(col="bildungsstand"))
```

Answer (score 0):

UDFs aren't very optimal solutions, especially for the Python - primarily because of the necessity to send data between JVM and Python.  Only when necessary it's recommended to use  [Pandas UDFs](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) that are better from performance point of view.

But in your case you can just use built-in [`when` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) like this:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import when,col
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("Bachelors", 13.0), 
       ("Masters", 14.0), ("Preschool", 1.0)], 
       schema=["bildungsstand", "bildungslevel"])
>>> df2 = df.withColumn("academics_category", 
   when((col("bildungsstand") == "Bachelors") | (col("bildungsstand") == "Masters"), 
      "academic degree").otherwise("no academic degree"))
>>> df2.show()
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|bildungsstand|bildungslevel|academics_category|
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|    Bachelors|         13.0|   academic degree|
|      Masters|         14.0|   academic degree|
|    Preschool|          1.0|no academic degree|
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Note that you need to use `|` as `or` operator, and `&` as `and` operator, and `~` as `not` operator

SparkByExamples has very [good description of this function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/)

But if you really have fixed list of values, then it's easier to use the [`isin` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) to check if value is in the list of given values:

P.S. I recommend to [grab this free book](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly) - Learning Spark, 2ed - it will give you good intro into Spark, its functions, etc.

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("Bachelors", 13.0), ("Masters", 14.0), ("Preschool", 1.0)], schema=["bildungsstand", "bildungslevel"])
>>> df2 = df.withColumn("academics_category", 
  when(col("bildungsstand").isin(["Bachelors","Masters"]), 
    "academic degree").otherwise("no academic degree"))
>>> df2.show()
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|bildungsstand|bildungslevel|academics_category|
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|    Bachelors|         13.0|   academic degree|
|      Masters|         14.0|   academic degree|
|    Preschool|          1.0|no academic degree|
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```